# When you click on "Tidy", "/>" from "<img/>" goes to the next line if there are too many characters

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, tidy

It's just a little thing, but I noticed that if an `img` element is closed like `<img />` and you click on the Tidy button, the `/>` is put on the next line when there are too much characters inside.

```css
img {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<br>
<br/>
<img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" />
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
/>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA90RVh0VGl0bGUAU2hvdztFeWU7SeMHJQAAAf1JREFUeF7tVjFrwkAYNf4JB2c3J+nf6OaYxdU/UVrsZAfByVGxQ8cgYhGSsXRoRHTIWi0VpJHSSrGg9Ou9c"
/>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA90RVh0VGl0bGUAU2hvdztFeWU7SeMHJQAAAf1JREFUeF7tVjFrwkAYNf4JB2c3J+nf6OaYxdU/UVrsZAfByVGxQ8cgYhGSsXRoRHTIWi0VpJHSSrGg9Ou" />
```

Note that I just deleted characters from the original `src` for the last 2 elements in the example.

(Also, a space is added before `/>` from `img` but not for `br`)

Comment: It'd make sense if this was happening at a lower width, but it requires quite a long line for it to begin wrapping html attributes.